# Extract all object names from PL/SQL file in Notepad++

Tags: sql, regex, notepad++

I need to get the function, procedure, cursor names and other objects from a PL/SQL package body file (*.spb) in Notepad++, for example from this sql script:

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY pac_emp3 AS
PROCEDURE p_buscar_salario_emp3 (p_employee_id IN employees.employee_id%TYPE,
                                 p_employee_name OUT employees.first_name%type,
                                 p_string IN OUT varchar2)
AS
v_salario employees.salary%TYPE;
BEGIN
SELECT salary, first_name INTO v_salario, p_employee_name FROM employees WHERE employees.employee_id = p_employee_id;
p_string := 'Procedimiento terminado';
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Salario: '|| v_salario);


END p_buscar_salario_emp3;

FUNCTION f_foo RETURN NUMBER IS
   SELECT 1+1 FROM DUAL;
   RETURN 1;
END;

END pac_emp3;
```

In this case, I need extract only:
PROCEDURE p_buscar_salario_emp3

or that the text looks only with the object and the name of the object:

```
PROCEDURE p_buscar_salario_emp3
FUNCTION f_foo
```

Same with FUNCTION names, etc.

I understand that it's possible with regular expression, but which one regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:\A|\G)(?:(?!(?:PROCEDURE|FUNCTION)).)*((?:PROCEDURE|FUNCTION)\s+\w+)(?:(?!(?:PROCEDURE|FUNCTION)).)*`
- Replace with: `$1\n` or `$1\r\n`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:\|\G)                    # non capture group, beginning of strig or restart from last match position
(?:                         # start non capture group
  (?!                       # start negative lookahead
    (?:PROCEDURE|FUNCTION)  # non capture group PROCEDURE or FUNCTION (you can add other keywords)
  )                         # end lookahead
  .                         # any character
)*                          # end group, may appear 0 or more times
(                           # start group 1
  (?:PROCEDURE|FUNCTION)    # non capture group PROCEDURE or FUNCTION (you can add other keywords)
  \s+                       # 1 or more spaces
  \w+                       # 1 or more word character
)                           # end group 1
(?:                         # start non capture group
  (?!                       # start negative lookahead
    (?:PROCEDURE|FUNCTION)  # non capture group PROCEDURE or FUNCTION (you can add other keywords)
  )                         # end lookahead
  .                         # any character
)*                          # end group, may appear 0 or more times
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group 1
\n          # linefeed, use \r\n for windows line break
```

**Result for given example:**

```
PROCEDURE p_buscar_salario_emp3
FUNCTION f_foo
```

Comment: But in case for example I need to search PROCEDURE and FUNCTION, how goes the regex?

Comment: \A.*(PROCEDURE|FUNCTION\s+\w+).*\z gets only FUNCTION, no PROCEDURE

Comment: @reymagnus: Use `\A.*((?:PROCEDURE|FUNCTION)\s+\w+).*\z`

Comment: Only gets the last string, (FUNCTION f_foo) in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work for you.

```regex
((PROCEDURE|FUNCTION) \S+)
```

If you need to add more terms, type them in like so:

```regex
((PROCEDURE|FUNCTION|NEW_TERM) \S+)
```

Comment: In this case, the regex replace the procedure name with blank space. I need to extract object and object name. How to inverse this regex to get this?